# Chromecast Audio stopped HTML 5 Web Audio API

Tags: android, audio, chromecast, jscript

Ok so i had this class working and playing sound. It suddenly stopped playing sound. If I debug it in the chromecast debugger all the data members get fill when I create an istance of it and call the init() function.

```
var audioplayer = new cast.AudioPlayer();
audioplayer.init();
```

Then after I am sure the .wav files are loaded, I call my play method

```
audioplayer.play(cast.AudioPlayer.welcome);//pass index of buffer
```

Here is the class

```
var cast = window.cast || {};

(function() {
'use strict';
AudioPlayer.applause = 0;
AudioPlayer.ding = 1;
AudioPlayer.buzzer = 2;
AudioPlayer.sigh = 3;
AudioPlayer.welcome = 4;

function AudioPlayer() {
    try {
        // Fix up for prefixing
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext
                || window.webkitAudioContext;
        this.context = new AudioContext();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
    }
    this.soundBuffer = [];
    this.loaded = false;
    this.sources = [];
}

AudioPlayer.prototype = {
    play : function(index){
        this.sources[index].start(0);//play then reload the buffer to reduce latency between user action and sound playing
        this.sources[index] = this.context.createBufferSource();
        this.sources[index].buffer = this.soundBuffer[index];
        this.sources[index].connect(this.context.destination);
    },

    init : function() {
        // Fix up prefixing
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext
                || window.webkitAudioContext;
        this.context = new AudioContext();

        var bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(this.context, this, [
                './sounds/applause.wav',
                './sounds/ding.wav',
                './sounds/buzzer.wav',
                './sounds/sigh.wav',
                './sounds/welcome.wav',],
                this.finishedLoading);

        bufferLoader.load();
    },

    //buffer up the sounds so they are immediately ready to play
    finishedLoading : function(bufferList) {
        this.sources[0] = this.context.createBufferSource();
        this.sources[1] = this.context.createBufferSource();
        this.sources[2] = this.context.createBufferSource();
        this.sources[3] = this.context.createBufferSource();
        this.sources[4] = this.context.createBufferSource();
        this.sources[0].buffer = bufferList[0];
        this.sources[1].buffer = bufferList[1];
        this.sources[2].buffer = bufferList[2];
        this.sources[3].buffer = bufferList[3];
        this.sources[4].buffer = bufferList[4];
        this.sources[0].connect(this.context.destination);
        this.sources[1].connect(this.context.destination);
        this.sources[2].connect(this.context.destination);
        this.sources[3].connect(this.context.destination);
        this.sources[4].connect(this.context.destination);
        this.soundBuffer = bufferList;

        this.loaded = true;
        console.log('Sounds Loaded!');
    }
};

// Exposes public functions and APIs
cast.AudioPlayer = AudioPlayer;

})();
```

And here is the buffer loader, sorry about the two different types of encapsulation.

```
function BufferLoader(context, cbObj, urlList, callback) {
   this.context = context;
   this.urlList = urlList;
   this.onload = callback;
   this.bufferList = new Array();
   this.loadCount = 0;
   this.callBackObj = cbObj;
}

 BufferLoader.prototype.loadBuffer = function(url, index) {
   // Load buffer asynchronously
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("GET", url, true);
   request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  var loader = this;

   request.onload = function() {
    // Asynchronously decode the audio file data in request.response
    loader.context.decodeAudioData(
      request.response,
      function(buffer) {
         if (!buffer) {
          console.log('error decoding file data: ' + url);
          return;
        }
        loader.bufferList[index] = buffer;
        if (++loader.loadCount == loader.urlList.length)
          loader.onload.apply(loader.callBackObj, [loader.bufferList]);
      },
      function(error) {
        console.error('decodeAudioData error', error);
      }
    );
  }

request.onerror = function() {
console.log('BufferLoader: XHR error');
    }

  request.send();
}

BufferLoader.prototype.load = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.urlList.length; ++i)
    this.loadBuffer(this.urlList[i], i);
}
```

I don't get it. I was playing audio fine. No errors are showing up in my debugger, just stopped working. I tested my chromecast with other apps as well. They all pass audio. Does anyone see any issues with this class?

I even step through it with the debugger, inspecting all variables as i go seem to have the data. The start() method just does not do anything.

Comment: OK I did some more testing with this using the crhome browser and it worked fine. Is there a volume control I am missing here. I see the one that comes on android with the casting interface. That is turned up all the way. Is there something that I am missing with volume control on the WEB API itself?

Comment: Just keeping a log of what i do. I added some gain control to the play method. It changes the volume in chrome, but still not change in chromecast.            //create the gain control
         var gainNode = this.context.createGain();
         // Connect the source to the gain node.
         this.sources[index].connect(gainNode);
         // Connect the gain node to the destination.
         gainNode.connect(this.context.destination);
         gainNode.gain.value = 4.0;
   this.sources[index].start(0);//play then reload the buffer to reduce latency between user action and sound playing

Answer (score 2):

The final solution for my problem was to replace the lines

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext
            || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();
```

with

```
var context = new window.AudioContext();
```

Seems the or (||) was favoring window.webkitAudioContext. This is a deprecated interface and does not work on my chromecast.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was something a miss with my chromecast device. I was getting audio from netflix so i started netflix and then launched my game to take over the chromecast. The audio just started working. Wasted about 48 hours on something that I cannot reproduce now. Any comments to why this can happen would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issues has resurfaced. Does anyone know of additional initialization that needs done.